# Compiled code doesn't execute file writes

Tags: c++, g++, ofstream

I have a class with a `run()` method that's supposed to write a "header" file, perform some calculations, and write the results of the calculation to a separate file. My problem is that the files never get written. VS code debugger seems to indicate that the `.close()` calls in the writing methods never get reached. Even when I try to intersperse `.flush()` methods the file doesn't get any content written, though.

The writing methods call on an inline variable declared in `Experiments.h`, which is `#include`d in the file.`Experiments::OUTPUT_DIR= "../results/".

I take it that the problem is the content never gets written because `.close()` never gets called in the compiled code. But how do I fix this?

```
// main method in the compiled file

int main(){
    Experiments::Experiment* experiment = new Experiments::UniformRandomAgentGameExperiment();

    experiment -> run();
}
```

```
// run() method on the experiment class (simplified)

void Experiments::UniformRandomAgentGameExperiment::run(){

    write_header();


    // Start  maintaining output file in memory, then dump at the end of the experiment

    std::string output_str;
    output_str.reserve(... a large number I calculate ...);
    output_str+="";


    // run all the tests
    int games_played=0;

    while(games_played<n_games){

        // Perform an iteration and accumulate results into output_str.

    }
    // I can verify at this point with simple std::cout that output_str has the content it should
    write_experiment(output_str);
}
```

```
// write_header() method

void Experiments::UniformRandomAgentGameExperiment::write_header(){
    std::ofstream header(Experiments::OUTPUT_DIR + fileheader+".header",std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc); // <- Debugger indicates this line gets visited

    header  << "Experiment Name: " << experiment_name << std::endl
            << "Experiment Description: " << description << std::endl << std::endl

            //... and write some more stuff ... <- Debugger indicates these lines get visited


    header.close(); // <- Debugger indicates this line is never reached
}
```

```
// write_experiment method

void Experiments::UniformRandomAgentGameExperiment::write_experiment(std::string data){
    std::ofstream logfile(Experiments::OUTPUT_DIR + fileheader + ".csv",std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc); // <- Debugger indicates this line gets visited in compiled code
    logfile << data; // <- Debugger indicates that this line and the next are skipped in compiled code
    logfile.close();
}
```

Comment: The situation you describe isn't really possible. How are you determining that this code isn't reached?

Comment: I guess I could be misinterpreting what the debugger is telling me. Here's what I'm doing: (1) compile with `-g` , (2) insert a breakpoint in VS code at every line in the write method, e.g. `write_header`, as well as at the call itself, (3) see what breakpoints get reached, by running the debugger and seeing where it stops.

When I wrote this question I had only put in a few breakpoints in the method. Upon inserting one on literally every line, a few break points are skipped as well as the final `.close()` commands.

Comment: Are you compiling with any kind of optimization enabled (`-O` options I think). They often mess up the correspondence between source code and machine code meaning its no longer possible to break on certain lines. None of this explains why you're seeing no output of course.

Comment: I have been compiling with `-O3` and thought that might be it too. Removing the flag in of itself doesn't seem to fix the fact that the file isn't written, though on debug it DOES get to `.close()`.

Comment: That's as I thought. There's some other reason you get no output. I susect the most likely reason is that the folder you are writing to doesn't exist, and therefore your files don't get created. You are using a relative path `../results/` etc so I think the folder that path is relative to is not what you think it is. To test that theory I would try using an absolute path, and if you see output in that case it would confirm the theory. Next step would be to work out what relative path you should be using instead.

Comment: The other thing you should do (and you should always do) it check that your files do actually open. `if (logfile.is_open())` etc. There's too many reasons that a file open might fail, so you should always check.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I changed `Experiments::OUTPUT_DIR = "results/"` (rather than `"../results/"`, it wrote!

The code containing `main()`, as well as the resulting compiled binary, was in a directory within my project root, and I had assumed I needed to specify a path relative to it. I was wrong - the path is apparently relative to where the compiled binary is called (or maybe where it was compiled from? idk).

So before this change, I guess the compiler saw it was trying to write to a non-existent location `"project_root/../results"` and tried to skip it altogether.